# A JavaScript loop in military time format

Tags: javascript

I want to do a JavaScript loop based on two times (in [military format](http://www.spacearchive.info/military.htm)), and that loop have to return a normal time.

For instance, I have this two vars:

```
var start_time = 1400; // That mens 14:00 or 2pm
var end_time   = 400; // Or 0400 (but it's the same the browser. It's 04:00 or 4 am
```

I want to do a loop, a for or while, and I want to give as a result this:

```
14:00
15:00
16:00
....
3:00
4:00
```

How I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: Just loop from 14 to 4 and then *display* the value in military time: `i + ":00"` would suffice in this trivial case.

Comment: All methods, for manipulating Javascript datetimes: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 4):

```
start_time = start_time / 100;
end_time = end_time / 100;

var x = start_time;
while(x >= start_time || x <= end_time) {
    if(x > 23) {
        x = 0;
    }
    console.log(x + ":00");
    x = x + 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4R8Dr/1/

Comment: Your loop will never start.  If x starts off as start_time (14) the first condition wont pass, nor will the second condition (end_time == 4).

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and providing a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea (room for improvement):

```
var start = 1400;
var end = 400;

if (start > end){
    end = end + 2400;
}

for (var i = start; i <= end; i += 100)
{
    var c = (i % 2400);
    var s = c + '';
    console.log(s.substring(0, c < 1000 ? 1 : 2) + ':00');
}
```

Output with node:

```
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00
18:00
19:00
20:00
21:00
22:00
23:00
0:00
1:00
2:00
3:00
4:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop in a for, incrementing the hour by 100. 
Just make sure to reset loop variable to 0:00 when you reach 24:00

```
function loopHours(start_time, end_time) {

    function write(hour){
        console.log( (hour/100) + ":00" );    
    }

    var hour = start_time;

    for (; hour != end_time; hour += 100) {

        if (hour >= 2400) {
            hour = 0;
        }        

        write(hour);

    }

    write(end_time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime) {
    var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0, 2), 10);
    var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
    var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

    return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};
$('span.mil_time').html(function (i, oldHtml) {
    return getFormattedTime(oldHtml);
});
```

Plus a loop that increase/decreases the variable by 100 and resets at 2400 to 0000 will do what you need. Don't forget this function requires jQuery and span tags with the id "mil_time"

http://jsfiddle.net/FsN6L/